# In Dynamics CRM is it possible to check the Execution Order from within the plugin context?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

When registering a plugin against Dynamics CRM you can specify the **Execution Order** (also known as Rank).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developer-articles/hh237515(v=crm.6)#bkmk_RegStep

> **Execution Order**
>   Specifies the order, also known as rank, that plug-ins are executed within a pipeline stage. Plug-ins registered with an order value of 1 are executed first, followed by plug-ins registered with an order of 2, and so on. However, if there is more than one plug-in in a stage with the same order value, then the plug-in with the earliest compilation date is called first.

I want to check the value of this from inside the plugin, can I do so, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, not directly from Plugin Execution Context but using another [retrieve service call](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/154063).

```
var rank = service.Retrieve("sdkmessageprocessingstep",context.OwningExtension.Id,new ColumnSet(new[] { "rank" })).GetAttributeValue<int>("rank");
```

Comment: Easy when you know how! Thanks!